# My Circle Image of Xamarin.forms opacity is not working on Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a own android renderer of Image for rounded image on Xamarin.forms. 
But it's opacity property is not working. 
When I set it's value, image disappears.

(iOS & Android under Lollipop, works fine)

My renderer is quite similar with this
https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/ImageCircle
This package is also not working when I set opacity.

It's really hard to make well working circular image.
Could you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Show how you set the opacity

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe Hi Sven, nothing special I put Opacity="0.5" from xaml or code. I also did init in activity file. and It works under Android Lollipop.

Comment: When this library called "canvas.ClipPath(path);" in drawchild method, image disappear. (works fine on under Lollipop)